# Should 'in-principle' be hyphenated?

Tags: british-english, hyphenation

Is it correct to say, 'your loan has been approved in principle' or 'your loan has been approved in-principle'.

Comment: _In principle_ should be hyphenated when it precedes the noun it modifies: _It has received in-principle approval_, but not if it follows: _It has received approval in principle_.

Comment: Yeah, in the first case "in-principle" is an adjective.  In the second case "in principle" is a preposition phrase (if I'm remembering 8th grade English correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three most likely ways to express your example sentence are in the following word orders:

> Your loan has been approved in principle.
>
> Your loan, in principle, has been approved.
>
> In principle, your loan has been approved.

In none of these cases would you hyphenate "in principle" because in each case it operates as a simple (two-word) prepositional phrase. The exception (as John Lawler points out in a comment above) would be if "in principle" were used as a compound modifier of a following noun, as in

> Your loan has won in-principle approval.

In that case, the hyphen serves to signal to readers that "in-principle" is an adjective phrase characterizing the kind of approval the loan has won, not a prepositional phrase spelling out in what respect the loan has won approval.